# XDEBUG works with URL but not with Cookie set

Tags: php, cookies, xdebug

my XDEBUG environment is setup and is working in most cases. I am working on a simple REST based web service which I can debug fine if I pass across the URI in the following format

```
POST http://192.168.1.121:8888/QDOSStatsLogger/statLogger.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Host: 192.168.1.121:8888
Content-Length: 295
Expect: 100-continue
```

When I try do the exact same thing with cookies set, it fails to start the debugger

This is what goes over the wire in the cookie situation (as seen in fiddler)

```
POST http://192.168.1.121:8888/QDOSStatsLogger/statLogger.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Host: 192.168.1.121:8888
Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP
Content-Length: 295
Expect: 100-continue
```

My output from phpInfo looks like the following with respect to xdebug. Am I missing something obvious?

```
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   tony    ECLIPSE_DBGP
xdebug.manual_url   http://www.php.net  http://www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp/xdebug/    /tmp/xdebug/
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) states:

> When the URL variable XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name is appended to an URL
>   Xdebug emits a cookie with the name "XDEBUG_SESSION" and as value the
>   value of the XDEBUG_SESSION_START URL parameter.

so cookie is called `XDEBUG_SESSION`, but your HTTP client seems to be passing cookie with another name:

`Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP`

Comment: You are of course absolutely right, thank you. I read that but obviously not well enough, it works great.